# One webroot, multiple ssl certificates

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I'm using the same codebase for two websites. Both need to be accessible through SSL. Is this possible with just one apache vhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

One virtual host can only ever be configured with one SSL certificate.

Further, to have multiple different certificates on a single IP address, you'd be using [TLS SNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication), which is still not practical to rely on for public web sites due to the fact that IE on Windows XP is not compatible with it.

So, for a multiple SSL certificate deployment, you'll probably need an IP per certificate (and a virtual host for each IP)

**However**, one option for you may be a Subject Alternative Name certificate, sometimes also called a "Unified Communications" certificate by the certificate authority vendors.  That would allow you to have a single certificate (and thus, a single virtual host) that works for both domains.

Comment: Not just IE on XP but also depressingly recent browsers such as the one on Blackberries and the previous version of the Android OS.